# Can not figure out why my Select Dropdown only updates once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using JQuery to update the defualt option of a select dropdown based on the value of another select dropdown. For some reason the update only works on the first change and I can not figure out why.

HTML:

```
<label>Enclosure Type:</label>
<select name="enclosure_type_it">
    <option value="global">Global </option>
    <option value="server_optimized">Server Optimized </option>
</select>
<div class="pure-control-group">
    <label>Handles:</label>
    <select name="handles_it" id="handles_datacenter">
        <option value="Semi Cylinder">Semi Cylinder</option>
        <option value="Combo_Security Handle">Combo/Security Handle </option>
        <option value="Comfort Handle">Comfort Handle </option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="pure-control-group">
    <label>Inserts:</label>
    <select name="inserts_it" id="inserts_datacenter">
        <option value="Pushbutton">Pushbutton </option>
        <option value="Locking pushbutton">Locking pushbutton </option>
        <option value="Locking">Locking </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#enclosure_type_it').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "global") {
        $('#handles_datacenter option[value="Semi Cylinder"]').attr("selected", true);
        $('#inserts_datacenter option[value="Locking"]').attr("selected", true);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "server_optimized") {
        $('#handles_datacenter option[value="Comfort Handle"]').attr("selected", true);
        $('#inserts_datacenter option[value="Locking pushbutton"]').attr("selected", true);
    }
}).change();
```

Still not sure what I am doing wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/y7easnb7/

Comment: Based on the code you've provided it shouldn't work at all. None of the elements have the ID of `enclosure_type_it`.

Comment: You are correct but i promise it did update those two selects the first time I would change it.

Comment: why use the name attribute at all?

Comment: @hogan The name attributes are being used later in the processing of the data. I can add ID's to all of the fields if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set value also you need to use `enclosure_type_it` as ID of select.

*HTML*

```
<select id="enclosure_type_it">
```

*Script*

```
$('#enclosure_type_it').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "global") {
        $('#handles_datacenter').val("Semi Cylinder");
        $('#inserts_datacenter').val("Locking");
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "server_optimized") {
        $('#handles_datacenter').val("Comfort Handle");
        $('#inserts_datacenter').val("Locking pushbutton");
    }
}).change();
```

If you want to use name attribute. Use following as selector

```
$('select[name="enclosure_type_it"]')
```

Comment: meh, maybe better to change the selector to `$("[name=enclosure_type_it]")` than changing `name` attribute to `id` attribute since it is a form.

Comment: @Onheiron, I agree with you.

Comment: Using the select name option you listed above I am still not getting it to update. I have added a link to the jfiddle I am testing with.

Comment: Thank you. I see I had not changed the .val() when setting the new option value.